# Excel: linking to data in CSV files

Tags: excel, csv

I have a Master excel file that links to several CSV files.  The CSV files are updated with new data on a daily basis:

For example, a link in the Master file may look like:

```
='P:\Model_Output\[JWN.csv]JWN'!$C$2
```

However, when I open the Master file containing the CSV links, I am prompted "The workbook contains links to other data sources." I click "Update."

But next, Excel flags "The workbook contains one or more links that cannot be updated."

When I investigate further, Excel says"open source to update values."

**When I open the CSV files, the data in the Excel file automatically updates.**

My question: **Is there a way I can have the data in Excel automatically update without opening each CSV file?** I know converting my CSV files to Excel may solve this issue, but I was hoping to explore a solution where I could keep my data sources as CSVs.

Thanks

Comment: will this answer suffice? http://superuser.com/questions/533018/open-a-csv-file-in-excel-and-have-it-update-whenever-csv-file-changes